# How to write a elasticsearch query for searching document with "someDateField is before today-28 days/2 months/1 year"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created this query to search for documents where empId is "XXXXXX" and joiningDate is before now (today's date).

```
GET employees/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "empId": "XXXXXX"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "joiningDate": {
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want help in modifying it to have the joiningDate condition as below
joiningDate is before now-10 days (today's date-10 days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "filter":[
            {
                "term":{
                    "empId":"XXXXXX"
                }
            },
            {
                "range":{
                    "joiningDate":{
                        "gte":"now-10d/d",
                        "lt":"now/d"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math has more on that